# Facebook native ads error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-audience-network, native-ads

I'm trying to integrate fb native ads in android but its giving me error every time I try to fetch an ad.

When I log the error its showing error code as -1 and unknown message

I have followed full documentation from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android/nativeadsmanager while integrating but couldn't find any solution

Thanks

Comment: There was a issue with gradle dependency. I replaced it with latest version and now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using the wrong dependency. Replace the following dependency (or whatever number you have before ***:+***:

```
 implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.+'
```

with

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.0.1'
```